# How do you float a control in VB.NET like you would in CSS

Tags: vb.net, layout

For example: how could I have 3 pictures aligned to the right all in one row, then when the far right picture is deleted the other two move to the right to fill that space. Code examples would be appreciated, thanks :)

Edit: I'm looking for this capability for both Windows forms and web forms. I'd be happy right now if I could just get the code for Windows.

Comment: WebForms? Winforms? WPF? Your question is very confusing, as it seems to imply both web and not-web.

Comment: Windows Forms and Web Forms both.

Comment: Please decide. Your question doesn't make sense. You are either using CSS or not.

Comment: @Blake: Why are you asking about web forms if you already know how it's done in CSS

Comment: I'm not using CSS, I'm using VB.NET, I'd like a way to float controls in VB.NET, the only thing I could think of though to compare it to was CSS

Comment: I'm building apps for both Windows and the web, if I need to do this a different way for each that's fine.

Comment: How are you adding the pictures to the form (assuming it is WinForms you are using)

Comment: Lets say just by adding a picturebox control to the form. Does it matter how they are added?

Comment: @Blake: If you're using "web forms", you are, in the end, outputting HTML, which can then be styled by CSS. Your comments are very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *windows-based* applications, Use `FlowLayoutPanel` control:

[FlowLayoutPanel in VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/1806/)

[FlowLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)

---

For *web-based* applications, use *Floating*:

[Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/)

[CSS float Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp)